# Coloring the Leaves of Dendrogram not by labels but by another variable in R

Tags: r, dendrogram, col

I have gone through other questions asked on this topic but have not found the answer to my case as yet. I want my dendrogram 's leaves to be color coded, but not by its labels; I want it to be coded by a different variable.

I have a DF with several columns. The first column holds "Markets" and the last column describes the "Color Codes" of these markets by assigning them "Red", "Yellow" or "Green" categories. Now, I want the labels of my dendrogram to be market names but the color codes to be given by the contents of the variable "color_codes".

What can I do so that the market labels/leaves of "CA" and "TX" are colored red, "MN" is colored yellow and "CO" is colored colored green, as per the color codes in the last column of DF? I also want the labels to be 'hanging'.

```
library(dendextend)
library(DEoptimR)

Markets         <- c("CA","TX","MN","CO")
Attribute1      <- c(1,2,4,4)
Attribute2      <- c(76,435,66,77)
Attribute3      <- c(24,3,4,34)
color_codes     <- c("Red","Red","Yellow","Green")

DF <- data.frame(Attribute1, Attribute2, Attribute3)

DF_scaled <- scale(DF)

row.names(DF_scaled) <- Markets
hc <- hclust(dist(DF_scaled)) 
dend <- as.dendrogram(hc)

dend %>% set("leaves_pch", 19) %>% set("leaves_cex", 2) %>% 
set("leaves_col", color_codes) %>% # adjust the leaves
hang.dendrogram(dend, hang_height = 1) %>% # hang the leaves
plot(main = "Hanging a tree")
```

This code gives the following error upon executing the last code block/line:

Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

[image]

Comment: It should be `hang.dendrogram(hang_height = 1)`, not `hang.dendrogram(dend, hang_height = 1)` (you are piping in the `dendrogram` via `%>%`). This just just a typo.

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I have been wondering for hours. Took you a few minutes to point it out.